# regexpr syntax in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying the following which should allow me to get everything between `productUrl://` and the following `?`

`(?<=\"productUrl\"\:\"\/\/)(.*?)(?=\?)`

The above works on https://regexr.com/

I am then trying to escape the backslashes to fit that string into the `grep` function but with no luck. What is the proper way of doing it ?

See this example: [link to example](https://regexr.com/45ug5)

I actually need to extract the substrings that match my pattern so `grep` may be used in conjunction with another function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note you do not need to escape `/` in R regex patterns as they are defined with string literals and `/` is not a special regex metacharacter. If you want to write a `"` inside `"..."` string literal, you should escape it with a single `\`, as you are already doing.

You may avoid overescaping here if you use single quotes to define the string literal and if you turn `.*?(?=\?)` into a negated character class:

```
grep('(?<="productUrl":"//)([^?]*)', x, perl=TRUE)
```

The `[^?]*` negated character class matches any 0 or more chars other than `?`.

If the string you are checking against has no double quotes remove them from the lookbehind:

```
grep('(?<=productUrl://)([^?]*)', x, perl=TRUE)
```

Instead of the lookbehind, you may also use `\K` to omit the part of text matched:

```
grep('productUrl://\\K[^?]*', x, perl=TRUE)
                   ^^^
```

Actually, you do not even need the capturing group in your pattern.

**Solving the actual task**

You cannot *extract* substrings with `grep` in R, you can only find/identify elements to fetch from a character vector using `grep`. To extract substrings, you need to use base R `regmatches` or stringr `str_extract`/`str_extract_all` or similar `match` functions.

Example with base R:

```
> x <- '":"ppath","value":[],"hidden":false,"locked":false}],"bizData":"","pos":0},"listItems":[{"name":"BRAND\'S® Lutein Essence 6 Bottles x 60ml","nid":"66765568","icons":[{"domClass":"lazMall","text":"LazMall","alias":"LazMallAlias","type":"img","group":"1","showType":"0","order":0}],\n"productUrl":"//www.lazada.sg/products/brands-lutein-essence-6-bottles-x-60ml-i138897006-s167303363.html?search=1","image":"https://sg-test-11.slatic.net/p/5337f879236ece2f14158c055adcdef7.jpg",\n"productUrl":"//www.lazada.sg/products/brands-lutein-essence-6-bottles-x-60ml-i138897006-s167303363.html?search=1","sku":"BR924HBAB3R0N4SGAMZ","skuId":"167303363"}],"restrictedAge":0,"categories":[1438,1565,4776,7305'
> regmatches(x, gregexpr('"productUrl":"\\K[^?"]*', x, perl=TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "//www.lazada.sg/products/brands-lutein-essence-6-bottles-x-60ml-i138897006-s167303363.html"
[2] "//www.lazada.sg/products/brands-lutein-essence-6-bottles-x-60ml-i138897006-s167303363.html"
```

With *stringr*:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract_all(x, '(?<="productUrl":")[^?"]*')
[[1]]
[1] "//www.lazada.sg/products/brands-lutein-essence-6-bottles-x-60ml-i138897006-s167303363.html"
[2] "//www.lazada.sg/products/brands-lutein-essence-6-bottles-x-60ml-i138897006-s167303363.html"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but your solution doesn't yield the expected result unfortunately. I might have several instances of the pattern so I do need the capturing group no ?

Comment: I tried `grep('(?<="productUrl":"//)[^?]*', a, perl=TRUE,value=TRUE)` following your advice

Comment: What is the input type? Is it a single string? Do you want to extract substrings (as matches) from it? You said you are trying to use it in `grep` command, that is why I used it in the answer.

Comment: I've put an input example in the link in previous comment : https://regexr.com/45ug5

Comment: @Chapo Then correct the question please. Please indicate if the input is JSON or not.

Comment: and I would like to extract the substrings from it yes. so `grep(...,value=TRUE)`

Comment: `grep` is not for extracting substrings, you are mistaken here.